# AudioTrack class with enqueue, play, stop, pause, resume

Tags: android

I need to create a class to handle audio AudioTrack.

In this class must have methods that enqueue audiotracks and play them in sequence synchronously.

Could anyone help me?

I do not know dequeue synchronously and play each part of the audio.

I need to use it because the data is passed to the audiotrack in byte [] is not on file. So I can not use the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code...

```
bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        if (bufferSize != AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE && bufferSize != AudioTrack.ERROR) {
            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    this.sampleRateInHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, this.bufferSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            if(audioTrack!=null && audioTrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED){
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Audio Track instance created buffer Size : "+this.bufferSize);

                audioTrack.setPositionNotificationPeriod(320);
                audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(this);
                audioTrack.play();
                short[] tempBuf =new short[bufferSize/2];

                            // now write the code here to fill the tempBuf by reading from the file in shorts or bytes
                audioTrack.write(tempBuf,0, tempBuf.length);



            }else{
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Unble to create AudioTrack instance");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to get the minimum buffer size");
        }
```